# How to make anchor click work from within ngFor loop in angular

Tags: angular, click, anchor, accordion, ngfor

I have a set of dynamic collapsible panels that open/close using the anchor tag. Placing the code inside ngFor, the click on anchor does not work.

Here is what I am trying to do. All the panels load correctly with expected data. The anchor link to close does not work though.

```
         <div *ngFor="let attribute of system.attributes;  index as i;">
          <div class="ibox">
            <div class="ibox-head">
              <div class="ibox-title">{{attribute.attributeName}}</div>
              <div class="ibox-tools">
                  <a class="ibox-collapse"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-body">
              <div class="row" >
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">{{attribute.description}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Try this one <a role="button" class="ibox-collapse"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

Comment: Thanks for replying Naseer. Tried out your suggestion but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following things to achieve this.

1- add click event with anchor tag.

```
<div class="ibox-tools">
     <a class="ibox-collapse" (click)="showInfo(i)"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
</div>
```

2- Assign an id to description panel.

```
 <div class="ibox-body" id="detail_{{i}}">
      <div class="row" >
           <div class="col-sm-12">
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{attribute.description}}</span>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

3- In typescript you have to make a function which open/close the panel using jQuery.

```
showInfo(id) {
    $('#detail_' + id).toggle();
}
```

**Now on clicking anchor tag close the panel and second click will again show the detail panel.**